# Strange behavior of %A format with non-public discriminated unions

Tags: f#

The output of:

```
type Test =
  | First
  | Second
  | Third

let test = First

printf "test=%A" test
```

is

```
test=First
```

as expected, but if I declare the type `internal`:

```
type internal Test =
  | First
  | Second
  | Third

let internal test = First

printf "test=%A" test
```

the output becomes:

```
test=FSI_0019+Test
```

Is this by design? Why? Or a bug?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with F# 2.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To print non-public members use the '+' flag. The fact that it is missing in MSDN looks like doc issue:

```
printf "test=%+A" test
```

Comment: Thanks! Glad it was not me overlooking something obvious

Comment: FYI, we've now updated it on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370560.aspx